# Rails creating unordered list in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am sorry if this question is not appropriate but I am trying to render an unordered list in HAML, HTML version looks like this:

```
<% @movies.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <ul class="comments">
    <li><%= comment.text %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I used 3 different html->haml online converters and all render this haml.

```
- @movies.comments.each do |comment|
  %ul.comments
    %li= comment.text
```

However the output is this (with 3 comments in a movie):

```
<ul class="comments">
  <li>asdasdasd</li>
</ul>
<ul class="comments">
  <li>asdasdasd</li>
</ul>
<ul class="comments">
  <li>asdasdasd</li>
</ul>
```

Why does this create 3 separate `ul` elements, instead of one and 3 `li` elements in it?

Answer (score 4):

It's not about HAML. It does what it does because you create `ul` element *inside* loop. What you want to do is to put root `ul` node on top:

```
%ul.comments
  - @movies.comments.each do |comment|
    %li= comment.text
```

Comment: Oh my, I am so stupid... :( Thank you for spotting this.